# How can I spoof WMI data?

Tags: windows-10

I want to add a fake KB to the OS, and see it using wmic qfe list. So do you know how can I create a faked KB? Or if it is possible to cause WMI to report a specific KB?

Comment: Very likely this information comes originally from the registry ... thing is that the modern (Windows Vista and newer) Windows update packages aren't as well documented as MSI for example, but they have some resemblance to the latter. So it stands to reason that the registry will contain references to the update packages installed and the WMI provider for the QFE will simply read it (possibly by some specialized API function, though, not necessarily registry functions).